# Mysql query using inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table `t`

```
id   a   b    c
1    1   1    1
2    2   1    1
```

and the table `t1`

```
id  a   b   c  p
1  1    1   1   47 
2  1    1   1   2
3  2    1   1   78
```

My purpose is to get a table

```
    id   a   b    c  p 
    1    1   1    1  49
    2    2   1    1  78
```

I tried the following script but it not works `@y=@y+t1.p` is always `null`  :

```
select t.id,t1.a, t1.b , t1.c ,@y=@y+t1.p from t1
inner join t
where t.a=t1.a
and t.b=t1.b
and t.c=t1.c
```

For more details [enter link description here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68a61/4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives the result you want:

```
select t.id,
       t1.a, 
       t1.b , 
       t1.c ,
       SUM(t1.p) from t1
inner join t ON t.a=t1.a and t.b=t1.b and t.c=t1.c
group by t.id, t1.a, t1.b, t1.c
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68a61/15)</kbd>

This uses SUM and GROUP BY. Make sure you use all the columns from the select in the GROUP BY to avoid undesired results.

Comment: That's right: the group by has been properly used. However, there could be a small improvement in terms of performance. Assuming the [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) sql mode is not set (which is the default) and assuming `t.id` functionally identifies all the the other fields in the `t` table then the group by could only be performed by `t.id`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the GROUP BY statement and use SUM

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  t1.a, 
  t1.b, 
  t1.c,
  SUM(t1.p) AS p
FROM 
  t1
  INNER JOIN t
     USING (a, b, c)
GROUP BY a, b, c
```

You can see it running [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68a61/9). It is possible to do it with variables but type of problem is usually solved with aggregate functions.

Comment: Note t.id is be random value now (your lucky its correct now).. I think you should read this http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/ and an demo with sql_mode -> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68a61/14.. check Filipe Silva's answer how it should be done..

Comment: Table t and t1 are linked with one to many relation, by using id from table t problem descibed in the dbsquare post will never occur and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is turned off by default.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `sum()` function over `group by` and `colease`. Plenty of examples in google.

[One link is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710147/mysql-sum-with-group-by-for-different-column-values)

Answer (score 1):

The calculation part needs to be done this way (if you need it sometime again)

```
SET @y = 0;

select t.id,t1.a, t1.b , t1.c ,(@y:=@y + t1.p) from t1
inner join t
where t.a=t1.a
and t.b=t1.b
and t.c=t1.c
;
```

see demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68a61/8